# javascript колбэки

Tags: javascript

Когда мы передаем функцию в качестве параметра другой функции, мы можем вызвать ее в любой момент внутри содержащей функции, как если бы функция обратного вызова была определена внутри содержащей функции. Это значит, что по сути функция обратного вызова является замыканием. Замыкания имеют доступ к области видимости содержащей функции, а значит могут использовать любые переменные, определенные внутри содержащей функции.

```
function boo() { 
    alert(a);
}

function foo(callback) {
    var a = 1;
    callback();
}

foo(boo);
```

Почему выдает ошибку, ведь

Замыкания имеют доступ к области видимости содержащей функции, а значит могут использовать любые переменные, определенные внутри содержащей функции.

Comment: этот материал я взял отсюда -getinstance.info/articles/javascript/callbacks-in-javascript -

Comment: где там написано, что колбэк видит/знает переменные доступные внутри функции, которая этот колбэк вызывает?

Comment: http://getinstance.info/articles/javascript/callbacks-in-javascript/

Comment: Прочитайте статью

Comment: да, Вы правы, фраза "как если бы функция обратного вызова была определена внутри содержащей функции" там действительно есть. Фраза эта неправильная. И это не единственный ляп. Например, "мы фактически передаем ее определение". Мы фактически передаем ссылку на объект функции.

Comment: В общем - не читайте тот сайт :-D лучше посмотрите в сторону [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript) - там хотя бы можно поправить неточность.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Внутри `boo` (колбэка) видны `а` и `b`, но не видно `c`.

```js
function callingFunction(callback) {
  var c = 4;
  callback(3);
}

function containingFunction() {

  var b = 2;
  
  function boo(a) { 
    console.log(a + b); // 5
    console.log(typeof c); // undefined
  }

  callingFunction(boo);
}

containingFunction();
console.log(typeof boo); // for @AntonShchyrov
```

Comment: что должен показывать данный ответ?

Comment: @Grundy, да вроде пример замыкания.

Comment: @Grundy что видно внутри колбэка

Comment: @Igor, стоит добавить пояснения в ответ

Comment: @AntonShchyrov - нет, не делает

Comment: @Igor виноват. Был введен в заблуждение

Answer (score 4):

Замыкания имеют доступ к области видимости не в момент вызова, а в момент создания. Это раз.

Далее - функции обратного вызова замыканиями не являются. Это указатель на объект функция. А как создавался этот объект вызывающую сторону не интересует

Comment: то есть получается, что статья которую я читал http://getinstance.info/articles/javascript/callbacks-in-javascript/ - это бред?

Comment: @ruslik все правильно `Замыкания имеют доступ к области видимости **содержащей** функции`, т..е. к функции, которая их **содержит**, а не вызывает. У Вас, т.к. функция `boo` объявлена глобальной, в качестве такой области видимости, выступает глобальная область видимости

Comment: Можете написать простой пример?

Comment: @ruslik пример чего?

Comment: все правильно - это ответ на вопрос или в статье все правильно

Comment: @ruslik В процитированной фразе ошибок нет

Comment: то есть я не правильно понял слова автора?

Comment: @ruslik, проблема в том, что авторы не дали определение _содержащей_ функции, поэтому нельзя сказать, что именно они имели ввиду. И судя по всему, да - у них ошибка.